# JavaScript quiz with multiple questions

Tags: javascript

Below I’ve made a small quiz with 4 questions and questions 2,3 and 4 are hidden with CSS, but you can try to remove the style from CSS `(".pytja2, .pytja3, .pytja4 { display: none;}")` to see all questions or put a style of `display: hidden` to each question one by one and you will see them.

I did that because I would like to show the next question when I click on the button **Next** then next question will show after I click **Next** button each time.
But there’s a problem that I have with question 2 it’s not showing and it doesn’t show any error in Console Log and I added on JavaScript a function that when I click button Next then the first question would be hidden and it would show the next question, but I do not know what’s wrong.

```
<div class="quiz">
        <div id="pytja1">
         <span class="quest1">I am a ?</span> 
        <form class="questions1" action="">
          <input class="correct" type="radio" name="gender" value="male"> Male<br>
          <input type="radio" name="gender" value="female"> Female<br>
          <input type="radio" name="gender" value="other"> Other<br>  
          <input id="bot" type="button" value="Next">
        </form>
      </div>
      <div id="pytja2">
        <span class="quest2">Football has letters ?</span> 
        <form class="questions2" action="">
          <input class="correct" type="radio" name="gender" value="male"> 7<br>
          <input type="radio" name="gender" value="female"> 5<br>
          <input type="radio" name="gender" value="other"> 6<br>  
          <input id="bot" type="button" value="Next">
        </form>
      </div>
      <div id="pytja3">
        <span class="quest3">VV stands for ?</span> 
        <form class="questions3" action="">
          <input type="radio" name="gender" value="male"> BMW <br>
          <input class="correct" type="radio" name="gender" value="female"> Volksvagen<br>
          <input type="radio" name="gender" value="other"> Audi<br>  
          <input id="bot" type="button" value="Next">
        </form>
      </div>
      <div id="pytja4">
        <span class="quest4">What year it is ?</span> 
        <form class="questions4" action="">
          <input type="radio" name="gender" value="male"> 2017<br>
          <input type="radio" name="gender" value="female"> 2015<br>
          <input class="correct" type="radio" name="gender" value="other"> 2019<br>  
          <input id="bot-submit" type="submit" value="Submit">
        </form>
      </div>
      </div>
```

```
.quiz{
  margin-top: 50px;
  margin-left: 40%;
  width: 250px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: coral;
}
.quest1{
  background-color: cadetblue;
  padding-right: 50px;
  margin-left: 30px;
  font-size: 22px;
}
.quest2{
  background-color: cadetblue;
  padding-right: 50px;
  margin-left: 30px;
  font-size: 22px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 3884px;
}
.quest3{
  background-color: cadetblue;
  padding-right: 50px;
  margin-left: 30px;
  font-size: 22px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 3884px;
}
.quest4{
  background-color: cadetblue;
  padding-right: 50px;
  margin-left: 30px;
  font-size: 22px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 3884px;
}
.questions1{
  margin-left: 28px;
  background-color: cyan;
  width: 220px;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 20px;
}
.questions2{
  margin-left: 28px;
  background-color: red;
  width: 150px;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 3925px;
}
.questions3{
  margin-left: 28px;
  background-color: greenyellow;
  width: 150px;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 3925px;
}
.questions4{
  margin-left: 28px;
  background-color: olivedrab;
  width: 150px;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 3925px;
}
.bot{
  margin-top: 10px;
}
.pytja2,.pytja3,.pytja4{
  display: none;
}
/* End of Quiz*/
```

```
let question2 = document.getElementById('pytja2');
let question3 = document.getElementById('pytja3');
let question4 = document.getElementById('pytja4');
let nextQuestion = document.getElementById('bot');
let result = document.getElementById('bot-submit');


nextQuestion.onclick = function () {
    if (nextQuestion === question1) {
        question1.style.display = 'none'
    } else if (nextQuestion === question2) {
        question2.style.display = 'block'
   }
}
```

Comment: There is no element with id `bot`. there are elements with `class="bot"`

Comment: @AlexKudryashev actually the first question has it. His code is kind of messy and inconsistent.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, but have you thought about using XHR/Ajax requests to retrieve the next question from the server upon having user click the Next button to go to the next question? You could then populate each respective div with the question/answers, and this would prevent users from being able to look at your source code and modify visibility. I know this is outside the realm of what you're asking, but might be food for thought...

Comment: @AlexKudryashev Changed Class to ID now, check it :)

Comment: @Woodrow I was thinking to do an easy project without Ajax or PHP because I still haven't learned Ajax yet

Comment: You could simply store the future questions in a JS object, and simply generate them when pressing next. Also, use a common class across similar elements, to not repeat your code - a simple .quest and .question test would reduce parts of your code by 75%.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, it appears there was some confusion on your use of `bot` as an `ID` and as a `CLASS` selector within your code. I took the liberty of cleaning this up and making it so the Next buttons use `.bot` as a `class`. If you're going to re-use a name value on an element, `class` is the syntax to use. `ID` is supposed to be specific to one element in the DOM.

Also, if you are creating a form to submit all answers, it would be better to declare `<form>` once, and then have each set of radio buttons contain the same name for each set of questions e.g (gender, car, etc.) so when you process the form, it will be easy to grab the selected choices by the user for each set of questions.

I cleaned up some of the CSS as well to help, and added a `for` loop that binds an `onclick` function to each Next `button` in the form, so upon each click, it will check the `parentNode.Id` to see what `div` elements it should hide and make visible for each next question block. This `for` loop is achieved by referencing the class `.bot` using `document.querySelectorAll('.bot');`

Please let me know if you have any further questions or need me to explain further the changes I made in the below snippet:

```js
let question1 = document.getElementById('pytja1');
let question2 = document.getElementById('pytja2');
let question3 = document.getElementById('pytja3');
let question4 = document.getElementById('pytja4');
let result = document.getElementById('bot-submit');
let nextButtons = document.querySelectorAll('.bot');

for (let i = 0; i < nextButtons.length; i++) {
  let nextQuestion = nextButtons[i];
  nextQuestion.onclick = function() {
    switchToNextQuestion(this);
  }
}

function switchToNextQuestion(nextQuestion) {
  let parentId = nextQuestion.parentNode.id;
  if (parentId === 'pytja1') {
    question1.style.display = 'none';
    question2.style.display = 'block';
  } else if (parentId === 'pytja2') {
    question2.style.display = 'none';
    question3.style.display = 'block';
  } else if (parentId === 'pytja3') {
    question3.style.display = 'none';
    question4.style.display = 'block';
  }
}

result.onclick = function() {
  alert('I am submitting the quiz!');
}
```

```css
form {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  padding-top: 50px;
}

.quiz {
  margin: 0px auto;
  width: 250px;
  height: 100px;
}

.quest1,
.quest2,
.quest3,
.quest4 {
  background-color: cadetblue;
  font-size: 22px;
}

.questions1 {
  margin-left: 28px;
  background-color: cyan;
  width: 220px;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.questions2 {
  background-color: red;
}

.questions3 {
  background-color: greenyellow;
}

.questions4 {
  background-color: olivedrab;
}

.bot {
  margin-top: 10px;
}

#pytja2,
#pytja3,
#pytja4 {
  margin-left: 28px;
  display: none;
  width: 220px;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 20px;
}


/* End of Quiz*/
```

```html
<form id="quiz-form">
  <div class="quiz">
    <div id="pytja1" class="questions1">
      <span class="quest1">I am a ?</span><br/>
      <input type="radio" name="gender" value="male" class="correct"> Male<br/>
      <input type="radio" name="gender" value="female"> Female<br/>
      <input type="radio" name="gender" value="other"> Other<br/>
      <input class="bot" type="button" value="Next" />
    </div>
    <div id="pytja2" class="questions2">
      <span class="quest2">Football has # letters ?</span><br/>
      <input type="radio" name="football" value="8" class="correct"> 8<br/>
      <input type="radio" name="football" value="5"> 5<br/>
      <input type="radio" name="football" value="6"> 6<br/>
      <input class="bot" type="button" value="Next" />
    </div>
    <div id="pytja3" class="questions3">
      <span class="quest3">VW stands for ?</span><br/>
      <input type="radio" name="car" value="BMW" /> BMW <br/>
      <input type="radio" name="car" value="Volkswagen" class="correct" /> Volkswagen<br/>
      <input type="radio" name="car" value="Audi" /> Audi<br/>
      <input class="bot" type="button" value="Next" />
    </div>
    <div id="pytja4" class="questions4">
      <span class="quest4">What year it is ?</span><br/>
      <input type="radio" name="year" value="2017" /> 2017<br/>
      <input type="radio" name="year" value="2015" /> 2015<br/>
      <input type="radio" name="year" value="2019" class="correct" /> 2019<br/>
      <input id="bot-submit" type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help and even a working quiz like I was planning, thank you :)
Just a question, why you used "if (parentId === 'pytja1')", why you didn't use button Next like this "if (nextButtons  === 'pytja1')", asking this because I would need first to click button Next and compare with "pytja1", "pytja2" etc..

Comment: You're welcome. The reason I did parentId === 'pytja1', is because when you click on one of the Next buttons, the onclick event will then check to see what parent node (<div id="pytja1">) the Next button is a child of to determine where the user is within the quiz steps. This allows the function to determine how to hide/show each question as you progress in the quiz.

Comment: Just to clarify, if you wanted to add specific ID's to each next button, so <input type="button" id="next-button-1" class="bot" value="Next"/> you could then reference the button ID value itself inside the onclick function, and compare using that ID value === "next-button-1" instead of looking at the parent node to determine what to hide/show. Few different ways to skin this proverbial cat.

Comment: Thank you for explaining :)